# Appropriate Data Structure for Inventory System

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am currently doing a school project for my Data Structures assignment. The inventory system prototype must be done in C++, consisting of two parts with specific functionalities Inventory (Add product, sort, search, filter, display all) and Transactions (View all, sort, add purchase).

Each inventory and transaction records has multiple attributes such as purchase date, price, time, etc (signifying the usage of 3d array?). Most of my peers are using linked lists, which I don't see any advantages in doing so (CMIIW). I am thinking that a dynamic array will suffice for this case scenario. I dont think this assignment has enough depth for this Data Structures course, can anybody recommend a good usage of data structures other than array for my project? Thank you!

Comment: When in doubt, start with `std::vector`.

Comment: I am currently thinking of arrays in a stack style to easily undo the changes. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not `std::map` ?